Button Clicking Help: Python, Selenium
I'm trying to web scrape an HVAC website. I want to put in a zipcode, hit the submit button, and then scrape the resulting information on the closest dealers. Here is the website if necessary.
My problem is that the zipcode I want is typed fine, but it won't submit. After the zipcode submits, I want to check a div for the text on the number of dealers, and based on that choose what to scrape into a csv.
Simplified HTML of the button:
<div class="dl-zipcode-search__block">
    <div class="zipcode-miles__wrap">
        <div class="dl-searchbtn__wrap">
            <button type="button" onclick="Search();">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Simplified HTML of the dealer count div with example zipcode:
<div class="dl-dealer-list__block" id="dealer-list-pagination">
        <div class="dl-dealer-count__block">
                <span>6 Dealers near <span id="searchedZip">35005</span></span>
        </div> 
</div>

I tried:
#modules here
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
import re
from time import sleep
import csv
#importing zipcode array
from array import array
#zipcode list is 2nd file with zipcode array
from zipcode_list import zip_arr


#function that checks the dealer count div
def is_multiple_dealers(driver):
        dealer = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.dl-dealer-count__block:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)')
        #checking if I am finding the dealer
        print(dealer)
        #boolean that returns true or false depending on if there are 0 results, and the text
        for d in dealer:
                if '0 dealers near' in d.text:
                        return False, d.text
                        break
                else:
                        return True, d.text
                        break
                break 


#main excerpt 
def main():
        #webdriver setup code here

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

        #webpage validation code here
        page_source = driver.page_source

        #zipcode array
        a = zip_arr

        for x in range(len(a)):    
                #zipcode form submitting code here
 
                #waiting until submit button is there then submitting
                submit_zipcode = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.dl-searchbtn__wrap > button')))
                submit_zipcode.click()

                #scraping with beautiful soup
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,features="html.parser")
        
                dealer_boolean, dealer_quantity_text = is_multiple_dealers(driver)
                if dealer_boolean == True:
                        print(dealer_quantity_text)
                        #find data and add to array
                else
                        #add an array entry as "NAN" for no dealers in the zipcode

        driver.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

Since I have been able to scrape another website with a zipcode entry and submit button fine I expected it to work.
Last three traceback lines:
File "C:\Path_to_file_here\Scrape_project.py", line 80, in main
    dealer_boolean, dealer_quantity_text = is_multiple_dealers(driver)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

The "print(dealer)" in the custom function shows up as
[]
so I'm guessing either my CSS Selector is wrong, or how I'm going about calling it? I also tried adding 'wait' as a parameter to the function to use 'wait.until' for the button to be visible but that didn't help either.

Selenium operates in real time.  My guess is that you're not waiting for the page to render before you try to read it.  BTW, your code above does not show where you get page_source from.

Based on the info you provided, i think you are having problem in locating the search button element, you can use the xpath //button[contains(., 'SEARCH')] to do that:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

timeout = 5 #time to wait for element to appar 

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get("https://www.goodmanmfg.com/support/find-a-dealer")
input_zip_code_elem = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='zipcode']")))
search_button_elem = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'SEARCH')]")))

input_zip_code_elem.send_keys("123456")
search_button_elem.click()

